# Change variable type phpDoc

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a base class that has several classes that inherit from it.

```
class Pet{
  ...
}
class Dog extends Pet{
   ...
}
class Cat extends Pet{
   ...
}
```

Then I have another class that consumes this class

```
class Person{
   /** @var Pet */
   public $pet;
}
```

These classes are based on some JSON object I will receive.  The JSON object could contain a Dog object, or a Cat object. I run a `switch` statement to figure out which it is at runtime and handle it appropriately. However I would like to have type hinting via PHPDoc for whether it's a cat or dog.  I have been unable to figure out how to specify at runtime that it's type has changed from a `Pet` to a `Dog`.  This didn't work - it still just thinks it's a plain old `Pet` object.

```
$pet = json_decode($jsonObj);
if($pet->type == "dog"){
   /** @var Dog */
   $pet = $pet;
}
```

Any idea how to change the type to a sub-type at runtime with PHPDoc?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following using [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php):

```
if ($pet instanceof Dog) {
    $dog = $pet;
    //now the IDE and runtime knows it is a Dog.
} elseif ($pet instanceof Cat) {
    $cat = $pet;
    //now the IDE and runtime knows it is a Cat.
}
```

Another way only using the DocBlock:

```
if ($pet->type === "dog") {

    /** @var Dog $dog */
    $dog = $pet;
    //now the IDE knows it is a Dog (at runtime this could be a Cat too).

} elseif ($pet->type === "cat") {

    /** @var Cat $cat */
    $cat = $pet;
    //now the IDE knows it is a Cat (at runtime this could be a Dog too).

}
```